# Error al ejecutar el login: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
 require 'conexion.php';
 $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");

 if($_POST['proceso_ingreso']=="iniciando"){
    if($_POST['nombreUsuario']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){
    #leyendo los paramentros ingresados
    $nombre =    $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
    $password =  $_POST["password"];


  $query = "SELECT *FROM registro WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND password = '$password'";
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    }

    if($numrows !=0){
        header('location: paginaDconsulta.php');

    } else{
      echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos vuelve a ingresarlos"; 
        }
    }


 else{
    echo "Por favor llenar todos los campos"; 
 }
  }
 ?>

<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Inicio de Sesion - Citas Medicas</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php">click para volver a login</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No puedes usar `mysqli_num_rows` **antes de obtener el resultado**, como lo estás haciendo ahora, si te fijas tienes dos llamadas a esta función, la que está antes de pasar la `query` a la bd, te da ese error. `Esta sobra -- > $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);<---`
`if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);` **Nota:** Tu consulta es vulnerable a [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)

Comment: Acá el problema es este "SELECT *FROM" el * está pegado al FROM. Dejá un espacio

Answer (score 2):

El error es bastante claro , **`intentas acceder al número de filas de un String más no de un Result que sería lo correcto`**.

En la línea  `$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);` *antes del if* , su variable `$query` es una cadena simplemente y  [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) espera un Resultado de un `mysqli_query`,  con borrar esa línea creo que ya solucionaría el error menor.

Pero no el más grande que aún posee, Es  dejar de lado las malas practicas que atentan contra la seguridad de su aplicación. [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php?noredirect=1&lq=1) proveniente de la concatenación de valores enviados por el usuario *entre otros*. además **`plantearse como obligatorio emplear Sentencias preparadas.`**